# Can I use a terminal wire kit meant for a dryer on an electric range stove?

Tags: electrical, dryer, wire, stove, range

So one of the terminal wires on my families range melted off (one of the 
 black wires) which was probably caused by a loose connection and they ordered a terminal kit but apparently it's meant for dryers. https://www.whirlpoolparts.com/PartDetail/Terminal-Kit/279318/469513
It seems to be the same type of wire but it has screws where the rings/lugs are suppose to go. This is probably a stupid question but if I unscrew those and just leave the hole and inserted into the block, would that work? Would it be able to handle the load and create a tight connection? If not, could I remove those and put a lug on the ends instead? The electric range model is a whirlpool WFE505W0HZ1

Answer (score 1):

Wait.  You are paying $32 for four #12 pigtails?

No, return them, they are too small anyway.  They should be #6 (if the breaker is 50A) or #8 if the breaker is 40A, unless it is a factory authorized replacement part for your exact model.

I would just go to an electrical supply house with the burnt pigtail and see if they have those lugs, or better, a premade pigtail in that color.  It won't be $32.

Comment: Yea, I figured they were a bit much for simple cables. Also my brother didn't realize they were meant for a dryer not a stove. So I was just hoping I could make them work. What's small about them? they aren't compatible? You're right tho it does make more sense to do it that way and return the wires. As a novice with wires, I had no clue what to even search for with cables except the color. So depending on my breaker I should be looking for a #6/8 cable for my white and black wire? Appreciate the help.

Comment: Well, cables are multiple wires inside a sheath.  Those look like individual wires.  I would take the old  one into an electrical supply house and see if they have the parts to make you one.  Too small  means they catch on fire.